# Does $S^n$ admit expansive homeomorphism for some $n \ge 3$?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, topological-groups, ergodic-theory, locally-compact-groups

I know that $S^1$ and $S^2$ admit no expansive homeomorphism. But I don't know for higher dimension $S^n$ for some $n\ge3$.

Definition: Let $X$ be locally compact metric space and $T$ is homeomorphism map on $X$ to itself. Then $T$ is said to be expansive if there exists positive real number $C$ and for any two distinct point $x$,$y\in X$ there exists integer number $n$ such that:

$$d(f^n(x), f^n(y)) > C$$

---

Edit:
That $S^2$ admits no expansive self-homeomorphism is a result of K. Hiraide ([1987 PNAS note](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195513507), 1990 Osaka J Math Paper).

Comment: But $S^2$ **does** admit an expansive homeomorphism. Simply use any pseudo-Ansoov homeomorphism with respect to a set of 4 points on $S^2$.

Comment: @user169239 Lee is referring to your introduction where you claim the opposite.

Comment: Here is a proof that S^2 does not admit expansive homeomorphism.( Thm 2) https://www.dropbox.com/s/04ar2swvj8rv1jz/KOICHI%20HIRAIDE_EXPANSIVE%20HOMEOMORPHISMS%20OF%20COMPACT%20SURFACES%20ARE%20PSEUDO-ANOSOV.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Oops, right, sorry. On each unstable leaf that curls around a 1-pronged singularity, one sees violations of expansivity.

Comment: I think that the existence of a simply connected closed manifold of positive dimension with an expansive self-homeomorphism is a famous open problem. (Note: one requires only $n\in\mathbf{Z}$ in the definition of expansiveness. Because the typical example, say the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ on the torus $\mathbf{R}^2/\mathbf{Z}^2$, would not be expansive with the definition restricted to natural numbers. What you say is called positively expansive.)

Comment: Sorry it's typo. Thanks for correction.